# CSS Bottom Right Border Gradient to Transparent

Tags: html, css, border, gradient

I need to put a black border going transparent from bottom to up but only on right side.

This code partially does exactly what I need, but I don't know how to make it disappear on the left side, so only the right side has the border...

```css
.bottom-to-top {
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-image: 
      -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 0 0, from(black), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
    -webkit-border-image: 
      -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
    -moz-border-image:
      -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;  
    -o-border-image:
      -o-linear-gradient(bottom, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
    border-image:
      linear-gradient(to top, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
}
```

Comment: underneath set border-left:3px solid black

Comment: The code i have has border exactly as i want but on both sides..
I want the left border to disappear.. Only right to be visble so right goes transparent from bottom to up

Answer (score 4):

just change `border-width: 3px;` to `border-width: 0 3px 0 0;` you were setting border on all the sides

```css
.bottom-to-top {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-width: 0 3px 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 0 0, from(black), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
  -o-border-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to top, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-to-top"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:after` :pseudo-element to do this.

```css
.bottom-to-top {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
.bottom-to-top:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, black, transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-to-top"></div>
```

Comment: The code SW4 posted, seems to work exactly as i want.. Its just that its not working on IE, but works fine with Chorome/Firefox
@chipChoko, i dont need the black border on all sides.. just the transparent one on right side..

Comment: @Rifshan: That could be because IE supports `border-image` property only from v11.

Comment: Chip, your code works fine in IE, can you just make the border appear on the right side, no border on the rest..... sorry if im nagging too much, but this is really complicated for me :/

Comment: @Rifshan: then in the .border-to-top class change the `border` `black` color choice to `transparent`.